# Getting tags associated with an API in Azure API Management

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-api-management, ibm-api-management, apim

Is there a way to get tags that are associated with an API through Powershell?

The [Get-AzApiManagementApi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.apimanagement/get-azapimanagementapi?view=azps-3.0.0) command returns the list of APIs, but tags are not included in its response.

Comment: Are you looking only by Powershell only ? By using Rest API , you can get it Tag - Get By Api https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2019-01-01/tag/getbyapi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `Get-AzApiManagementApi` will not return the tags of each API, the workaround is to use [`Get-AzResource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azresource?view=azps-3.0.0).

Try the script as below, it returns tags of each API.

```
$ResourceGroupName = "<resource-group-name>"
$APImg = "<API-Management-service-name>"
$ApiMgmtContext = New-AzApiManagementContext -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ServiceName $APImg
$Apis = Get-AzApiManagementApi -Context $ApiMgmtContext
foreach($Api in $Apis){
    $ApiId = $Api.ApiId
    $ApiName = $Api.Name
    $tags = (Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ResourceType Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis/tags -ResourceName "$APImg/$ApiId" -ApiVersion 2018-01-01).Name
    Write-Host "Tags of" $ApiName : $tags
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From Powershell Try this . You can also get this from resource explorer .

Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName Integration-Resources -ResourceType Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/tags -ResourceName "integration-common/test" -ApiVersion 2018-01-01

By using Rest API , you can get it Tag - Get By Api https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2019-01-01/tag/getbyapi

You can also follow this GitHub Issue for reference.  https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/21817